# Polymer paper-dialog iron-overlay-closed not working

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, paper-elements, polymer-starter-kit

I'm using a paper-dialog like following:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-body.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-overlay-behavior/iron-overlay-behavior.html">

<paper-dialog id="addNoteDialog" iron-overlay-closed="test" iron-overlay-opened="test">
  <h2>Add a new note</h2>
  <paper-input autofocus required="true" id="title" label="Title of your note"></paper-input>
  <paper-input id="note" label="Enter your note"></paper-input>
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button dialog-confirm>Accept</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

However the function `test` never does get executed... Have I forgot to import something or am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I was using `iron-overlay-closed`, it has to be `on-iron-overlay-closed`